# How to update hibernate in glassfish 3.1.1?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, glassfish-3

in order to get some bugs fixed I have to update the Hibernate version shipped with glassfish 3.1.1 from 3.5 to 3.6.
I'm using netbeans 7.0.1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is not shipped with Glassfish. The default JPA provider in Glassfish is **EclipseLink**.
If you mean, that you're using hibernate bundled with **NetBeans**, that's another question. But I would prefer to manually set up my environment rather than using some embedded libraries.